# The jenkins build fails when any testng test case fails. How to make it so that the build succeeds when all test-cases are run regardless of result?

Tags: testng, jenkins

In my Test Automation, when we execute the TestNg Suite XML then whenever any test case fails the Jenkins Build also fails.

But I require that the TestNG report shows the proper result, either Pass or Fail, and at same time the jenkins build should show success because all test case executed.

I understand that TestNG throws either a hard or soft Assertion on any test case failure.  And I guess due to that exception the whole jenkins build also fails.

Comment: It's hard to understand exactly what the question is

Comment: I think the question boils down to this: **How do I prevent failures in a TestNG suite from failing my entire Jenkins job?**.  @user3591670 Exactly how do you run the TestNG suite?  Do you use the "Invoke Ant" build step, or something else?  If the latter, please be specific.

Comment: Could you try re-wording your question?  include what you want to happen and what is stopping that from happening.

Comment: A tad cheeky remark: You may want to rethink your test-cases. There is a reason it works like this: Failed test cases means *the build does not work and is broken*. Perhaps you need a different way to determine all your test cases are doing their proper job?

Comment: Requirement is bit tricky for me. Because when I drill down and found that I need to resolve my problem from TestNG prespective instead of Jenkins. Thanks for feedback as I am working towards solving it at my automation framework level.

Answer (score 1):

I am new so i cannot comment, to get more details

If this is maven build, try adding

```
-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true
```

into MAVEN_OPTS, advance button in build section of jenkins